# Dockerfile can not see package.json file

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

I've got this structure of the project:

```
- project
-- apps
--- microservice-one
---- Dockerfile
-- package.json
-- docker-compose.yml
```

Here is my `Dockerfile` from the `microservice-one`:

```
FROM node:12.13-alpine As development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install 
COPY . .

RUN npm run build

CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

and docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  microservice-one:
    container_name: microservice-one
    build:
      context: ./apps/microservice-one
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    expose: 
      - '3000'
    command: npm run start
```

why after run `docker-compose build`, my console throw me this error:

```
#12 0.725 npm ERR! code ENOENT
#12 0.726 npm ERR! syscall open
#12 0.728 npm ERR! path /usr/src/app/package.json
#12 0.729 npm ERR! errno -2
#12 0.734 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.json'
```

I think that the problem is in my Dockerfile and `COPY package*.json ./`, is a chance that my `Dockerfile` can not see `package.json`?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The package.json is not in /apps/microservice-one but 1 level higher, therefore docker cant find it. Also, your second volume looks invalid. But at build time, this will not affect you yet. But you will get to that issue in the next step.

Answer (score 2):

When your context is `./apps/microservice-one`, the Dockerfile can only copy files from that directory and directories below it.

Your Dockerfile is written as if it assumes that the context is the current directory, so if you change the context and the dockerfile values in the docker-compose file, it should work.

```
services:
  microservice-one:
    container_name: microservice-one
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/microservice-one/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    expose: 
      - '3000'
    command: npm run start
```

Answer (score 1):

From your filesystem structure the directory hosting `Dockerfile` is the build context -> `microservice-one`.

When you perform a `docker build ...`, the build context and all it's content gets wrapped up and sent over to the docker daemon, which then tries to build your container. At that time there is only access to the build context, nothing outside. ( https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#build-with-path )

So unless you move/copy your file over it will remain invisible.